# Getting the parameters from lmfit

Tags: python, lmfit

I am doing a fit in python with lmfit and after I define my model (i.e. the functio I want to use for the fit) I do `out = model.fit(...)` and in order to visualize the result I do `plt.plot(x, out.best_fit)`. This works fine, however this computes the value of the function only at the points used for the fit. How can I apply the parameters of the fit to any x vector (to get a smoother curve), something like `x_1 = np.arange(xi,xf,i), plt.plot(x_1,out.best_fit(x_1))`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Including a complete, minimal example that shows what you are doing is always a good idea.  In addition, your subject is not a good reflection of your question. You have now asked enough questions about lmfit here on SO to know better.

You probably want to use `ModelResult.eval()` to evaluate the ModelResult (probably your `out`) for a given independent variable.  If you need more help, ask an answerable question that might be useful to others...